# MVC Controller Shopping Cart adding to a list

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make a shopping cart and I'm having trouble with adding an item to the shopping cart.

I'm trying to add items to the carts, but it seems that it is refreshing itself everytime I call the ShoppingCart part of the controller.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ANON_Capstone.Models;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
    Carts carts = new Carts();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Courses()
    {

        return View(db.Courses.ToList());

    }

    public ActionResult ShoppingCart(string className, string classPrice, string classID, string classDesc)
    {
        if (carts.CartModels == null)
        {
            carts.CartModels = new List<CartModel>();
        }
        CartModel cart = new CartModel();
        cart.className = className;
        cart.classPrice = Convert.ToDouble(classPrice);
        cart.classID = Convert.ToInt32(classID);
        cart.classDesc = classDesc;

        //if (className != null)
        //{
        //    carts.CartModels.Add(new CartModel() { className = className, classPrice = Convert.ToDouble(classPrice), classID = Convert.ToInt32(classID), classDesc = classDesc });
        //}

        if (className != null)
        {
            carts.CartModels.Add(new CartModel() { className = className, classPrice = Convert.ToDouble(classPrice), classID = Convert.ToInt32(classID), classDesc = classDesc });
        }

        //Session["Cart"] = cart;
        //ViewBag.Name = Session["Cart"] as ANON_Capstone.Models.Carts;
        //ViewData["Cart"] = cart;
        Console.WriteLine();
        return View(carts);
    }
}
}
```

Courses.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ANON_Capstone.Models.Course>

@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
@section featured
{
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <h2 class="text-center">Please Login or Create an Account to make a Purchase!</h2>
        </div>
    </section>
}
}

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <h2><strong>Courses</strong></h2><br />
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 col-s-8 col-lg-4">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("ShoppingCart", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" />
                <h2>@item.className</h2>
                <p>$@item.classPrice -- @item.maxStudent spots left! </p>
                <input type="text" name="className" value="@item.className" hidden="hidden" />
                <input type="text" name="classPrice" value="@item.classPrice" hidden="hidden"  />
                <input type="text" name="classID" value="@item.ClassID" hidden="hidden" />
                <input type="hidden" name="classDesc" value="@item.classDesc" />
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Add to Shopping Cart" />
                }
            }
            <br />
        </div>
    }
</div>
</div>
```

ShoppingCart.cshtml

```
@model ANON_Capstone.Models.Carts
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}


<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateCommand", "PayPal"))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @if (Model.CartModels.Count != 0)
        {
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Course Image</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Course Desc</th>
                <th>Course Price</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.CartModels)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                    <td>@item.className</td>
                    <td>@item.classDesc</td>
                    <td>@item.classPrice</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />
        }

        else
        {
            <text>Your shopping cart is currently empty</text>
        }
    </div>


</div>
}
```

Carts.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Models
{
public class Carts
{
    public List<CartModel> CartModels { get; set; }
    public double CartTotal { get; set; }
}
}
```

CartModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ANON_Capstone.Models
{
public class CartModel
{
    public string className { get; set; }
    public double classPrice { get; set; }
    public int classID { get; set; }
    public string classDesc { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating new instances of Carts and CartsModel on every page call rather than loading them from the database.

Web-based applications are stateless, they don't remember variables across requests.

You'll need to write some code to persist and load your cart across multiple requests.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. In my home controller, I made sure to create an instance of Carts outside the controllers. Does it still instantiate it everytime I visit a page on home controller? If it does, what method should I use to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is a new instance every time. You need to give your cart an id and save it to database at the end of every call to the ShoppingCart method. You also need to add a CartId parameter to the ShoppingCart method to load the correct cart from the database on every call.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to involve your `foreach` in a "IF" block case and you'll escape your `foreach` from a new refresh.

```
@if(Model.CartModels != null){
foreach (var item in Model.CartModels)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="~/Images/party.gif" style="width: 175px" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                    <td>@item.className</td>
                    <td>@item.classDesc</td>
                    <td>@item.classPrice</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </table>
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />
        }

        else
        {
            <text>Your shopping cart is currently empty</text>
        }
}
```